# Ace-editor not working on other pages - AngularJS App

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ace-editor

I am trying to use ACE Editor to display code (JSON response) on a page. When I try the ace example on the landing page, `index.html`, it works. But when I use the same code on `page2.html` it wont work.

**HTML**

```
<div id="editor">
  function foo(items) {
   var i;
   for (i = 0; i &lt; items.length; i++) {
     alert("Ace Rocks " + items[i]);
   };
</div>
```

**SCRIPT:** the same code works on index.html but wont work when placed on other pages.

```
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
```

I even tried putting the above js code on an external file `<script src-"js/script,js"></script>` with hopes it will be available on any page.

Since its an AngularJS App, `page2.html` and other pages are loaded via `ngView`

Comment: i guess your var editor = ace.edit("editor"); is evaluted before the content og page2.html is loaded...

Comment: ahh yes putting it on `page2.html`'s Ctrl instead of the html works. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Michael suggested, Ace is evaluating `var editor = ace.edit("editor")` before the content of the page is loaded.
Instead of using the script in the html or in an external script I had to put the script code inside the `page2.html` controller....

```
function page2Ctrl ($scope, $http) {
 var editor = ace.edit("editor");
 editor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
 editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
}
```

When app goes on `page2.html` the page's ctrl gets initiated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function inside script then put the 
`var editor = ace.edit("editor");`

```
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
```

inside the same function. 
You can also do:

```
   function doOnLoad()
    {
        var editor = ace.edit("editor");
        editor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
        editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
    }
```